# makeobj command not found error

Tags: macos, bash, makefile, build-tools

I'm trying to run `make` command on a new Mac machine (OSX).

```
shubham@IN:~/code/xps/bus_boarding_paper$ make
-bash: makeobj: command not found
```

My Makefile is as follows:

```
title=bus_boarding_paper
target=$(title).pdf

all: pdf

bus_boarding_paper.pdf: pdf

pdf: $(title).tex title_page/*.tex
    pdflatex $(title).tex
    bibtex $(title).aux
    pdflatex $(title).tex
    pdflatex $(title).tex
```

There is no related post online with a clear solution. SO also shows no results.

What does this error message mean? It is not clear to me.

PS: Another friend of mine had this problem on Fedora too.

Comment: What's the output of `type make`?

Comment: make is aliased to `makeobj'

Comment: And have you got `makeobj` installed and on your `$PATH`? Alternatively, remove that alias.

Comment: No makeobj is not there. I did `brew install makeobj`. Nothing found.

Comment: So... no. To summarise; you run `make`, `make` is an alias for `makeobj` in your shell, you haven't got `makeobj` so Bash tells you that it can't run `makeobj`.

Comment: I can't find anyway online to install makeobj in Mac. Can you give me some direction or clue about where to look?

Comment: Why have you got that alias in the first place?

Comment: No idea how. I just have Xcode installed, that's all.

Comment: Figured it out. So make was aliased by a .kde-bashrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was using a kde-bashrc file which aliased make to makeobj. You can figure out details using `type make` and then figure out accordingly.

I unaliased make and I was good to go.